# Loop in R (Bioconductor ALL dataset)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm using the ALL dataset from the Bioconductor suite.

I have the following linear model for gene expression levels at time-of-remission.  I've been able to create a model for one specific gene, but cannot develop a loop or apply () snippet that will work on each row (12K).

I've updated my packages to include limma and developed the following model:

```
> ourData <- exprs(ALL)
> ourDataFactor <- ourDataFactor <- pData(ALL)$age 

> design <-model.matrix(~ ourDataFactor)
> fit <- lmFit(ourData, design)
> fit <- ebayes(fit)
> topTable(fit)
```

However, I keep getting the following error for the lmFit step (also not showing as a function with help(lmFit).

```
> fit <- lmFit(ourData, design)​

Error in lmFit(ourData, design) : 

  row dimension of design doesn't match column dimension of data object
```

Why can't I complete this step?  I know it deals with my pData (data frame) that has 128 rows and my exprs (matrix) has 12625.  The patients are what map the two datasets and reside in rows for pData and in columns for exprs.

Comment: If you're doing linear models for microarrays, I'd look at [limma](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html), which is designed to work with Bioconductor's data structures. It can handle continuous outcomes with a bit of work in designing the models.

Comment: I've updated my packages to include limma and developed the following model:

> ourData <- exprs(ALL)
> ourDataFactor <- ourDataFactor <- pData(ALL)$age 

> design <-model.matrix(~ ourDataFactor)
> fit <- lmFit(ourData, design)
> fit <- ebayes(fit)
> topTable(fit)
However, I keep getting the following error for the lmFit step (also not showing as a function with help(lmFit).

> fit <- lmFit(ourData, design)

Error in lmFit(ourData, design) : could not find function "lmFit"
Why can't I complete this step?

Comment: Did you `library(limma)` ?

Comment: yes, thanks.  Now I have a new problem.  row dimension of design doesn't match column dimension of data object

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. Most importantly, your example code is not reproducible: `days2remiss` is not defined anywhere. Also for future posts, *always* include any external library/data you load.
2. Consider the following

   ```
   library(ALL)
   data(ALL)
   expr <- exprs(ALL)
   ```

   `expr` contains gene expression values per patient (column) per Affymetrix probe ID (rows). Expression from *multiple* probes (i.e. the probe set) characterise the expression of a single gene. So fitting a linear model to just a single probe makes no sense. You need to map probe IDs to some gene identifier (Entrez, Ensembl, etc.) and then summarise expression values on the gene level. After that you can model *gene* expression in a statistical (linear) model.

Comment: Thank you Maurits.  I should have included some of my earlier steps where I covert date.cr and diagnosis into variables.  I've updated my question above.

Comment: *"I've been able to create a model for one specific gene"* As I explained, you're *not* creating a model for a single gene. You're fitting a model to a single probe. That's very different. Gene expression is measured by a *set of probes*. It's easy to show how to run a model for every gene (e.g. using `purrr::map`), but you first need to summarise expression values at the gene level.

Comment: @Oars PS. I agree with neilfs' comment. `limma` is (still) the number-one tool for (differential) gene expression analyses of microarray data. You should definitely check it out. `limma` comes with a *very* good and comprehensive vignette.

Comment: Ok, I already created a linear model (lm.34852) for a gene.  How would I know build a model for the entire 12k set of genes?

Comment: @Oars ***"34852_g_at"* is *not* a gene. It's a probe ID. Expression from a single probe ID does not characterise the expression from the associated gene. Expression from the probe set (multiple probe IDs) characterise expression from a single gene.**

Comment: Thank you Maurits.  If I can create characterize expression for this probe ID (one of 12625), I'm simply trying to write a loop to do the same for the reminder.  I found this example on the web and trying to adapt it to my scenario.            mypvals <- c()
    for (i in 1:dim(mydata)[1]) {
    apelm.sum <- summary(lm(mydata[i, ] ~ species))
    pval <- pf(apelm.sum$fstatistic[1], apelm.sum$fstatistic[2],                 apelm.sum$fstatistic[3], 
        lower.tail = FALSE)
        mypvals <- c(mypvals, pval)